# Dedupe table in SQL and get latest non-null values for each column to update gold record

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

Having this table called `raw_data`:

```
+---------+------------+-----------------------+-------+------+------+
| user_id | updated_at |         email         | val1  | val2 | val3 |
+---------+------------+-----------------------+-------+------+------+
|       1 | 2022-01-01 | john.smith@domain.com | true  | 1    | null |
|       1 | 2022-01-02 | john.smith@domain.com | null  | 2    | null |
|       1 | 2022-01-03 | john.smith@domain.com | null  | null | 3    |
|       2 | 2022-02-01 | jane.doe@domain.com   | true  | null | 1    |
|       2 | 2022-02-02 | jane.doe@domain.com   | false | 1    | null |
+---------+------------+-----------------------+-------+------+------+
```

and this gold record table:

```
+---------+------------+-----------------------+------+------+------+
| user_id | updated_at |         email         | val1 | val2 | val3 |
+---------+------------+-----------------------+------+------+------+
|       1 | 2022-01-01 | john.smith@domain.com | true |    1 | null |
+---------+------------+-----------------------+------+------+------+
```

I am trying to work out a SQL query that can upsert the gold record table based on newest values.

This means that the table in the end should look like this:

```
+---------+------------+-----------------------+-------+------+------+
| user_id | updated_at |         email         | val1  | val2 | val3 |
+---------+------------+-----------------------+-------+------+------+
|       1 | 2022-01-03 | john.smith@domain.com | true  |    2 |    3 |
|       2 | 2022-02-02 | jane.doe@domain.com   | false |    1 |    1 |
+---------+------------+-----------------------+-------+------+------+
```

The idea is that:

1. a new row is inserted for user_id 2 (as it didn't exist before).
2. the user_id 2 row has `val1` set to `false` (the latest value) as well as `val3` = 1 as opposed to just `null` which would from the latest row.
3. user_id 1 gets updated with new values from other rows like `val2` = 2 and `val3` = 3. Each of those values come from different rows but are the latest values for that user.

As far as available SQL goes, this would be run on Amazon Athena over an S3 data lake. The main challenge is that the updated golden user record would come from multiple rows, so a simple partitioned `ORDER BY updated_at` type approach would not work as the latest record in `raw_data` does not have all information for that user.

As far as the approach goes:

- rebuilding the full gold table from `raw_data`
- or using the gold table as a reference to limit the number of records
  for each user that `raw_data` has to be queried for

are equally valid (although for cost and performance optimization, the second method would be preferable).